# Custom editText with varying text size like Instagram

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-edittext, android-custom-view

I am implementing a feature in android app where size of text in multiline editText varies depending on number of characters in that line.

[Here is what i want to achieve.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHrLk.jpg)

I was wondering how to achieve this. Any guide or direction will be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this according to your requirement: [AutoAdjustEditText](https://github.com/ViksaaSkool/AutoFitEditText)

or in simple way:
Add this to your build.grade:

```
repositories {
    //...
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
```

and then in dependencies:

```
dependencies {
            compile 'com.github.ViksaaSkool:AutoFitEditText:53238e2d29'
    }
```

then add in your layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="333dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary" >

    <com.autofit.et.lib.AutoFitEditText
        android:id="@+id/rET"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        android:maxLength="240"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="90sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks @aj0822ArptiJoshi for quick response. Will look into this.

Comment: okk @Gaurav and if  my answer accepted then please check right and voted.

Comment: Hey @aj0822ArpitJoshi i was trying to implement custom editText like 'instagram Type' where text size of each line adjusts according to no of characters is that particular line. Whereas  above mentioned  library provides autoFitText functionality.

Comment: Instagram Type means? could you elaborate.

Comment: In Instagram there is a 'Type Mode'  which let users post stories using words. Here is the link http://metro.co.uk/video/instagram-type-mode-lets-post-stories-using-words-1619738/?ito=vjs-link

Comment: @Gaurav Any updates, I too am working on the same thing. I have wrote down an algorithm, building on the greedy approach of word-wrapping, but it is far from perfect and causes a dent in perfomance.

Comment: @KiranMathewMohan haven't implemented yet.